# Create a xml tag dynamically using xslt in a for each

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

`Input:`

```
<grouphead-web channel="Tablet/HeraldSun" id="U101641278497RAG">
    <headline-web>
        <p>HS Tablet Extended Head Tablet</p>
    </headline-web>
</grouphead-web>
<grouphead-web channel="Web/HeraldSun" id="U101641278497f0H">
    <headline-web>
        <p>AUS Extended head Web</p>
    </headline-web>
</grouphead-web>
```

`Expected Output:`

```
<herald.com.au>
  <mpp>HS Tablet Extended Head Tablet</mpp>
  <web>AUS Extended head Web</web>
</herald.com.au>
```

I am using a for each to iterate over the tag but i am getting below output

`Actual Output:`

```
<herald.com.au>>
  <mpp>Tablet Data</mpp>
</herald.com.au>>
<herald.com.au>>
  <web>Web Data</web>
</herald.com.au>>
```

Code is used to iterate the tag to get the output:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$groupHeadWeb[@channel]">
    <ixsl:f test="@channel != 'Web,Tablet'" group-by="substring-after(@channel, '/')">
        <xsl:variable name="mppValue" select="if (starts-with(@channel, 'Tablet/')) then headline-web/p else ''" />
        <xsl:variable name="webValue" select="if (starts-with(@channel, 'Web/')) then headline-web/p else ''" />
        <xsl:variable name="domain" select="substring-after(@channel, '/')" />
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;',myfunc:getDomain($domain),'&gt;')" />
        <xsl:if test="$mppValue != ''">
            <mpp>
                <xsl:value-of select="$mppValue" />
            </mpp>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$webValue != ''">
            <web>
                <xsl:value-of select="$webValue" />
            </web>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;/',myfunc:getDomain($domain),'&gt;')" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong in the process?? Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: "Any suggestions what i am doing wrong in the process??" Well, if you expect people to fix your XSLT code then show it to us.

Comment: Updated the code as well. @MartinHonnen

Comment: How are you getting the name for the <herald.com.au> element?  This is a URL.  But it is not in your xml or your XSLT.  Also, are there only two <grouphead-web> elements possible in  your input XML?  If not I would recommend showing more in both the input and the output.

Comment: Are there more input elements? Are those two `grouphead-web` that form one result element (e.g. `herald.com.au`) always siblings? Then process one to create the result element and inside select or process the contents and that of the sibling. Otherwise use some grouping (positional?) or based on `group-by="substring-after(@channel, '/')"` (?).

Comment: @Bluewood66 i wrote a function to return the <herald.com.au>. There can be multiple <grouphead-web> in the xml file.

Comment: @MartinHonnen
Are there more input elements? `Yes` 
Are those two grouphead-web that form one result element (e.g. herald.com.au) always siblings? `No , there will be other tags as well. example <autralian.com.au>`
Otherwise use some grouping (positional?) or based on group-by="substring-after(@channel, '/')" - `Used this but did not give the expected result`